# beforeSave callback doesn't work in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

In my Menu model I'm trying to fill the slug field if the user didn't fill it.

```
Model/Menu.php

    public function beforeSave($options = array()){
            if(
                isset($this->data[$this->alias]['name']) && 
                !isset($this->data[$this->alias]['slug'])
            ){
                     //than fill the slug field in the db for the user.
                $this->data[$this->alias]['slug'] = strtolower(Inflector::slug($this->data[$this->alias]['name'], '-'));
            }
        }//end function
```

but it doesn't work all the data are saved without going throught this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not going through that method at all.  If it was, it would not save, since you didn't `return true;` per the instructions in the [CakePHP Book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforesave).

You're likely saving Menu data through an association of another model - in which case, it would use IT'S beforeSave, not this one.